# AWS RDS instance is not publicly acessiable

Tags: amazon-rds

I have created a MySQL RDS instance on AWS under free-tier. I can access the Database with endpoint and username password on MySQL workbench software to upload my schema and even on localhost I can fetch data from DB on my local page running on xampp.
But when I try to fetch it from another machine it couldn't be accessed. 
I tried lost of other systems.

As I'm new to AWS I wanted to know that if free-tier RDS instance will be only accessing from my system or AM I missing something like any settings like inbound and outbound rules?

Let me tell you guys I want to use it for collage project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Head over to your rds instance and take note of the security group ID. In the ec2 menu you can set inbound and outbound rules for that security group.